# Parsing XML file into a dataframe in R using XML library

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing

I'm making a program in R that is supposed to parse an XML file and use the info in the file.  I wrote these lines of code:

```
library("XML")
library("methods")

x <- xmlToDataFrame("sample.xml")

print(x)
```

and tested it.  Please note that the above is the entire program.  I get the following error with every single XML file I put into it:

```
> x <- xmlToDataFrame("sample.xml")
Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'sample.xml'
> 
> print(x)
Error in print(x) : object 'x' not found
>
```

Included in the XML files I've tested I've used this XML file:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762271(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Are you sure you saved the XML to the file correctly? The function doesn't seem to think your file contains XML. What does `readLines("sample.xml")` return?

Comment: It returns: Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'sample.xml': No such file or directory

Comment: OK. well, it sounds like the file doesn't even exist. Are you sure it's in your current working directory (`getwd()`)?

Comment: Are you sure path of the "sample.xml" is correct and that is available in working directory?

Comment: I wasn't in the working directory.  It works now